# AVPLAYER won't show on the view but plays sound

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

So I'm working on a player using AVFoundation, I can get it to play, but it won't show on the view. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing to get it to show on the view?

Here's my code:

```
    self.playerUrl = NSURL(string: playerStr)!
    self.player = AVPlayer.playerWithURL(self.playerUrl)! as! AVPlayer
    self.playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(layer: self)
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    self.player.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your working code:

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

In your code you are making mistake in this line:

```
self.player = AVPlayer.playerWithURL(self.playerUrl)! as! AVPlayer
```

Just change it with this:

```
self.player = AVPlayer(URL: playerUrl)
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you, I actually had it like that before I pasted and it didn't work so I made the change, but I also was setting the player to the layer AFTER I was doing CGRectMake, and that was dumb of me sorry.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

I have code from a previous app that uses MPMoviePlayerController, which is outdated (they suggest you use AVPlayer), that I know works. You can try it.

```
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: playerStr)!
    self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    if let player = self.moviePlayer {
        player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height/2 + 50)
        player.view.sizeToFit()
        player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.None
        player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
        player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One;
        self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        player.play()
    }
```